# What are the effects is a person has a regular amount of Deep Sleep and REM sleep but a lot less Light Sleep?

Tags: sleep, sleep-cycles, sleep-deprivation

It's commonly said that it's important that we get enough total sleep time. I however wonder how important the time in Deep Sleep and REM happens to be. What are the effects when a person has a regular amount of Deep Sleep and REM but a lot less Light Sleep?